# Wildfly log date on every stack trace line

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I use wildfly and have a problem with the output of the FILE log handler. It prints every line of an error of a stack trace with the full formatted form. Here it is a cutted example:

```
12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48) org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException: Realm [XXX.account.library.security.shiro.ClientApplicationRealm@14896aa1] was unable to find account data for the submitted AuthenticationToken [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - XXX, rememberMe=false].
12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48)   at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:184)
12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48)   at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48)   at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48)   at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
...
```

I just wanted to have the the line with `"12:13:11,238 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48)"` once at the beginning and every party of the stack trace beginning with "at" not as a new log line interpreted as a new log line.

I have an additional SMTP log handler and there is the same problem. So it sends an email for every line of the stack trace and not one email per error or exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like someone has left something like the following in their code:

```
  try {
      // do something that throws an exception
  } catch (SomeException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I would be really surprised if this was in Apache Shiro code.

In general it's a good idea to use one of the many logging libraries around and report it like:

```
  } catch (SomeException e) {
      logger.error("Something failed", e);
  }
```

In some cases if you're using a console appender or handler defined in a logging configuration within your deployment this may also cause this. The reason being is that WildFly wraps both `System.out` and `System.err` in a logger. This would result in the format you're seeing.

Comment: I do not print any stack trace. Additionally I use logback in the application so I have two log files, the server log and the application log. I already do the exception handling in the way you described it and the application log with logback looks fine but the same error in the wildfly server log looks like described above so i think this is a problem with the wildfly error handling.

Comment: Are you using a logback ConsoleAppender?

Comment: Great, that was the correct hint. I deleted the console appender and it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins do you want to add your correct answer? I will delete my incorrect one.

Comment: I'll just edit this answer with the ConsoleAppender as another option. The answer is correct given the original question.